# How to show an outside website like google or bing within a master page

Tags: css, asp.net, iframe

I have created a website using a master page.  One of the links within the master page is for Googles website.  I can display the google website within the master page by inserting the website within a Iframe, but the problem is when I do a search in google and I click on the links some of the links within google do not open.  After some reading I find that some websites do not allow their sites to open within an iframe "You have to check for HTTP response header X-Frame-Option of those sites. if its value is "DENY or SAMEORIGIN", then you can not load those website in the iframes.".

So does anyone know of another way to display an outside website within a master page?

This is my content page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Google.aspx.cs" Inherits="OnCallWeb.Google" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
    <p>
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1" style="width:100%;height:700px;"></iframe>
</asp:Content>
```

This is on my master page.

```
<li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Google.aspx")%>">Google</a></li>
```

Comment: Why? If Google doesn't want you showing their content on your site, why are you trying to override their wishes? What is your actual use case for doing so?

Comment: The goal is to have one stop shopping within our website.  Our site is internal for a 911 center.  We are looking for a way so our dispatchers can access our website and also be able to to do google searches without having to open new pages.  Speed is the goal.  The faster our dispatchers can easily access data the better.

Comment: Can't they just open Google in a new tab? I don't think you're really going to speed things up like you're hoping by doing this (assuming it's possible in a mainstream browser, which I highly doubt). If you want control over how the browser works, you'd need to write a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Google no longer supports Iframes